# Create Single PDF without page break

Tags: vue.js, pdf, pdf-generation

I want to generate PDF from the HTML without page break as i have table view. I don't want to break the pages. Applying download option in vueJs.

I tried with basic PDF generate option but all options are breaking the page.If there is any other solution also welcome.

Comment: An imaging toolkit like [LEADTOOLS Imaging SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/image-processing) could load the HTML file as a single raster image by specifying the appropriate width and height to the [CodecsRasterizeDocumentLoadOptions](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/dh/co/codecsrasterizedocumentloadoptions.html) class before loading with the [RasterCodecs](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/dh/co/rastercodecs.html) object. Once loaded, the image can be saved as PDF. (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor)